# Why is the output of my function in binary?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I wrote a differentiable Heaviside function and vectorised it. However, the output seems to be odd and binary. The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def heaviside(x, epis):
    if (x>= epis):
        y=1
    elif (x< -epis):
        y=0;
    else:
        y = 0.5 + x/(2*epis) + np.sin(np.pi*x/epis)/(2*np.pi);

    print (x, y);
    return y;

x1 = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100);
vheaviside = np.vectorize(heaviside);
y1 = vheaviside(x1, 0.2);
plt.plot(x1, y1, 'b', alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

The input is an array in `[-1, 1]`, and the outputs are supposed to be a continuous Heaviside function. However, all of the output is `0` or `1`. Why?

Comment: All your output is not actually 0 or 1

Comment: "continuous Heaviside function" doesn't turn up any relevant Google hits. What's a continuous Heaviside function? The only Heaviside function I know of is discontinuous.

Comment: Also, are you sure all the output is 0 or 1? When I run this code, `y1` has plenty of values that aren't 0 or 1, right where you'd expect them to be.

Comment: @user2357112 they are shown by `print`, but **not** in `y1` (at least when I run it).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Oh, whoops. You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler and more efficient way of defining a vectorized Heaviside function with Numpy would be using [`numpy.piecewise`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html):

```
def heaviside(x, epis):
    return np.piecewise(x, (x>=epis, x<-epis),
             (1, 0, lambda x: 0.5 + x/(2*epis) + np.sin(np.pi*x/epis)/(2*np.pi) ) )
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify when you [`vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) the function that it should be using `float`s:

```
vheaviside = np.vectorize(heaviside, [float])
```

otherwise, per the documentation:

> The output type is determined by evaluating the first element of the input

which in this case is an integer. Alternatively, make sure `heaviside` always returns a float, by replacing e.g. `y = 1` with `y = 1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is only discontinuous one.Try this:

```
def h(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0.5

    return 0 if x < 0 else 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but this Heaviside function is not differentiable.